# Return part of string with comment markers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking for the most efficient way to get a portion of the string and using a HTML comment as the start/end points.

So for example I want to use

```
<!-- START: Variable -->

stuff goes here

<!-- END: Variable -->
```

The string should just be the stuff in between the comments. I've made a helper but not really great with .net.

```
@helper readPattern(string filepath, string patternSection = null) {

    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filepath);
    string SplitBy = "<!-- START: "+patternSection+" -->";

    string fullLog = tr.ReadToEnd();

    fullLog.Trim().StartsWith("<!-- " + patternSection+ " -->");

    //string[] sections = fullLog.Split(new string[] { SplitBy }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     <div class="@patternSection">@fullLog</div>
}
```

I don't need to split it, I just need to output or trim it from the comments I pass through this helper.

Comment: You can use Substring 2 times

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the start and the end, and then grab what's in between.  The "in between" is from range `start + start string length` with `end - (start + start string length)` length

```
@helper readPattern(string filepath, string patternSection = null) {

    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filepath);
    String SplitBy = "<!-- START: "+patternSection+" -->";
    String EndBy = "<!-- END: "+patternSection+" -->";

    String fullLog = tr.ReadToEnd();

    int start = fullLog.IndexOf(SplitBy);
    int end = fullLog.IndexOf(EndBy);

    String data = fullLog.Substring(start + SplitBy.Length, end - (start + SplitBy.Length));

    <div class="@patternSection">@data</div>
}
```

You'll also want to `Close`/`Dispose` of your reader, by the way.  And if my assumption is right, and this helper will be used with the same `filepath` over and over, it would do you good to cache the contents of the file instead of reading it over and over again for each call to a different `patternSection` you call.  That'll end up being a LOT of file opening and closing for an otherwise static file.

Comment: How would you cache it? How would you close it, sorry I am new at this. also I get a error on the data string, Splitby doesn't seem to be in context

Comment: I had a typo of `Splitby` instead of `SplitBy`.  The advice I offered is about as good as I can get, short of fully writing the code for you, sorry.  SO expects a minimal understanding of the task at hand.  Since your question is mainly about getting the data between the comment block, try to get my code working and, if it does what you need, mark it as the answer.  And then, if you have other questions, hit the boards and see if there's an answer for you; if not, feel free to ask another question.  Good luck!